# Android build.gradle Error: "Cannot invoke method android() on null object"

Tags: java, android

I tried to change the app's version in build.gradle and when I tried to sync the console shows "Cannot invoke method android() on null object" error (At line 1) and "com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle".
If I try to revert to the old changes the error appears the same.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.x.y"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a newline.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
```

should be

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
```

Comment: It works, thanks you. I hadn't really noticed

Answer (score 0):

not working

Build file 'D:\AndroidData\AnasolProjects\NewFreeDataApp\app\build.gradle' line: 12

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Cannot invoke method testInstrumentationRunner() on null object

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34909962)